has_all(): failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant
I have a dynamic list of strings that I want to compare with a value of a column in main_table. I want to make sure all the parts from this list match my column.
let name_parts_table = print names = dynamic(["a.b", "a"])
| mvexpand name
| project parts = split(name, "."), Placeholder = 1;
main_table
| extend Placeholder = 1
| join kind=inner name_parts_table on Placeholder
| where components has_all (parts)

Error:
has_all(): failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant

I checked the documentation of has_all which also accepts a dynamic list of values for comparision.

Dynamic expression is supported in has_all() function. But you cannot give row level expression. Sample case for the supported dynamic data type is given in this microsoft document. There is a workaround for your case. Below is the code.
let name_parts_table = print names = dynamic(["a.b","e"])
| mvexpand names
| project parts = split(names, "."), Placeholder = 1;
maintable
| extend Placeholder = 1
| join kind=inner name_parts_table on Placeholder
| mv-expand parts
| extend parts=tostring(parts)
| extend check=iif(components has(parts),1,0)
| summarize available= minif(check,check>=1) by components
| where available == 1
| project components

In this solution, the mv-expand operator is used to expand the parts column into multiple rows, and then the has() function is used to check whether each row in the main_table contains the corresponding part from the name_parts_table. Since the parts column is expanded and checked for individual element of that column, it is then grouped based on the components column and checked if all the elements of parts column are part of components.
